# Alternatives to AutoHotkey on Windows

Tags: windows, macros, autohotkey

AutoHotkey is a fine piece of software - with one exception that the macro language is awful.

I'm wondering if there are alternatives to it on Windows, with a different macro language. Preferably an alternative with a language that's more conventional (such as [Phoenix](https://github.com/kasper/phoenix) on macOS which uses Javscript).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what features of AutoHotkey are the ones you use? You can use it to emulate the mouse, keyboard interactions and you can build whole GUIs using it (last time I checked). Having some information on what you need might get you some better results.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: You should check out: [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). . . . . . The best in my experience!! This is software shopping though unfortunately.